# How to create dynamic images with text of MS Word Art

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, dynamic-image-generation

I am able to create simple image with text, but I want to apply MS Word Art font to my text.
Any Reference link or help appreciated.

here is my code to create image with Text.

```
Font MyFont = new Font(FontFamily, Font,FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
MyGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
MyGraphics.Clear(Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["bgColor"])));
MyGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
MyGraphics.DrawString(sImageText, MyFont,
                    new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["TextColor"]))), 0, 0);
MyGraphics.Flush();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Applying MS Word Art to text in images isn't supported by the .NET Framework libraries but you can apply certain effects. For examples, see [Bob Powell's article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006110746/http://bobpowell.net/texteffects.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your reply, if you see this thread http://forums.asp.net/p/1434707/4380294.aspx/1?Re+implement+functionality+like+quot+word+art+quot+  you will someone accomplish this

Comment: the link you have provided, I am already able to apply those effects, but My requirement is apply word art effect or create images with similar text style.

Comment: There are different styles—which Word Art style do you want to apply?

Comment: something like... http://cheerzone.com/Lettering/ImageGenerator.aspx?text=Akhtar%20Khan&font_family=Arial&layout_style=Point&background_style=Connected&color_style=TwoColors&color1=000000&width=1000

Comment: if you notice, this is in asp.net, this one already developed by someone and I need to create similar one. that means it is possible and must be some work around.

Comment: They either use custom code or a third-party library. You can do it yourself with GraphicsPath.Warp()—check out the link.